# Swift 3 Firebase chat application duplicate messages

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3

I was hoping for some advice/help. I have come across a neat little bug in the chat application I'm running that is currently using the anonymous Firebase authentication based around SWIFT3.

Once in the chat room of the application, and I return to the home/login page it appears to almost keep the previous user that was logged in on the current device and act as though you are multiple people. This makes it so that when sending a message, it returns two (or more depending on the amount you return to home/login and continue to the room) chat bubbles.

The one method I've tried was a response on this site previously, I believe it was "try! FIREAuth.auth().signOut()" attached to an @IBAction however I'm not sure if this is designed for anonymous users also?

I'm currently away from my code and can't give any snippets until this evening, but I will certainly answer anything I can until that point.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous accounts function just like any other account, so can be logged out using `FIRAuth.auth().signOut()`.

It's not possible to have more than one `FIRAuth.auth().currentUser` associated with a single device, so my best guess would be that you have multiple models being initialised for every controller initialisation.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Could this be due to the way I'm peddling back to the Home/Login page, I'm using Navigation Controller to return to the previous pages, again apologies I can't give the exact code right now, but I believe it's using Push Modal to the Navigation Controller which in turn access the Root View Controller. Hope that helps?

Comment: Using a navigation controller should be deinitialising your controller, but the model may not being deintialised if its being strongly referenced somewhere. Hard to say without the code really, I'll have another look when you can post some.

Comment: Thanks, what piece of the code would be best for you to take a look through? I have 3-4 controllers I believe, but the two I think would store the issue are the controllers for the Chat Channel list and the Chat Room itself.

Comment: Is there an easier way to send you the code? It's far too large to fit into this box.

Comment: After watching Firebase and the way the application is running I think the error might be located within the amount of calls the SENDERID is receiving?
I've add the code of the viewChatController here (ignore the deinit code I was testing it):
[link](https://pastebin.com/vF7Pp7Ws)